# "Lequel" as relative subject pronoun (instead of qui)

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-relatifs

To return to my favorite theme, my Louis Segond translation of the Bible has this for Exodus 1:8:

> Un nouveau roi vint à régner sur l'Égypte, **lequel** n'avait pas connu Joseph.

I would expect *qui* here. Indeed, [the other translations I've checked](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ex%201%3A8&version=BDS;LSG;NEG1979;SG21) use different wordings:

> Un nouveau roi vint au pouvoir en Egypte; **il** ne connaissait pas Joseph. (BDS 1992)
>
> Il s'éleva sur l'Égypte un nouveau roi, **qui** n'avait point connu Joseph. (LS 1910, Génève 1979)
>
> Un nouveau roi parvint au pouvoir en Egypte, **un roi qui** n'avait pas connu Joseph. (LS 2007)

English Wiktionary [doesn't even list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lequel) the subject use of *lequel*, but French Wiktionary [does](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lequel):

> S’emploie à la place de *qui*, surtout pour éviter une équivocité.

Its only example is from 1911, but [the TLF entry](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lequel) brings it up to 1938, if I read it right.

Does it still have this use today or has it been mostly reduced to the English Wiktionary uses — i.e. only after a preposition or to ask "which one"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to H. Ferrar's [A French Reference Grammar, Oxford University Press](https://www.amazon.co.uk/French-Reference-Grammar-H-Ferrar/dp/0199120331/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1532340151&sr=1-1) (p. 231), **lequel** is used in the **Nominative**, in written language only, in order to avoid ambiguity, where the normal use of **qui** would leave some doubt as to which antecedent was referred to. The book is a little bit old (my reprint dates from 1988) but I guess this is relevant even nowadays.

> La poignée du couteau, **laquelle** était en ivoire.

Here **laquelle**, being feminine, must refer to poignée.

If both antecedents are of the same gender and number, **lequel** is considered to refer to the **former** one.

> Une amie de sa sœur, **laquelle** venait parfois le dimanche. (i.e. une amie)

Trying to translate from the Greek Bible this particular verse:

> And a new king arose over Egypt, **who** did not know Joseph.

The [Revised Standard Version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revised_Standard_Version) (Nelson) has:

> Now there arose a new king over Egypt, **who** did not know Joseph.

In Greek language we have a pronoun (o opoios in modern Greek, [ostis in old Greek](https://www.studylight.org/lexicons/greek/3748.html)) which is essentially like **lequel** as relative subject pronoun. That is, it may be used to avoid ambiguity. So I think

> Il s'éleva sur l'Égypte un nouveau roi, **lequel** n'avait pas/point connu Joseph.

is the closest to the Greek text.

Comment: This answer seems to contain the most detail. Merci ! P.S. Not sure of the relevance of the Greek; the original text is in [Hebrew](http://biblehub.com/interlinear/exodus/1-8.htm), where the word אֲשֶׁר *asher* "which" is actually ambiguous as to the referent (though the verbal agreement on "know" might work since it seems to be 3ms for מֶלֶך *melekh* "king" and not 3fs for מִצְרָיִם *Mitzraim* "Egypt"). I don't seem to see *ostis* in the [Septuagint](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lxx/exo/1/8/s_51008), but I'm a very unpracticed reader of the Greek alphabet.

Comment: @LukeSawczak The greek text I referred to is written in the so called katharevousa (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katharevousa). The version of Septuagint (Ἀνέστη δὲ βασιλεὺς ἕτερος ἐπ᾿ Αἴγυπτον, **ὃς** οὐκ ᾔδει τὸν Ἰωσήφ) uses indeed **ὃς** which interpreted in the modern greek by  "Αλλά, μετά καιρούς, ήλθεν άλλος βασιλεύς εις την Αίγυπτον, **ο οποίος** δεν εγνώριζε τίποτε περί του Ιωσήφ ". The Greek text does not leave any ambiguity. It refers to the king and not to Egypt. I think Louis Segond uses lequel for this reason. With qui it might be a little unclear.

Comment: https://www.ellopos.net/elpenor/greek-texts/septuagint/chapter.asp?book=2&page=1                                                                                                             8 ᾿Ανέστη δὲ βασιλεὺς ἕτερος ἐπ᾿ Αἴγυπτον, **ὃς** οὐκ ᾔδει τὸν ᾿Ιωσήφ.           8 And there arose up another king over Egypt, **who** knew not Joseph.     The English translation (with who) has this ambiguity or not?

Comment: Oh, interesting! Thanks. Since Louis Segond was translated from the Hebrew, I still don't see any cause and effect from the Greek to the French, but it is good to know that this is how they interpreted it too. In English "who" is unambiguous since it refers to sentient beings — the alternative meaning would be written "Egypt, which" or "the Egyptians, who".

Comment: The Bible is a great place to learn/study another language. My wife learnt Greek in this way:-)! Myself, I use it to learn German. I am happy being useful. You have helped me a lot with your answers!

Comment: According to my LS version (1910 and subsequent re-editions (Génève)) the author used both the Hebrew and the Greek original texts. The same holds true for Semeur version. It is not specified (without error of my part) if the Old Testament was completely translated from the Hebrew text or the Septuagint's version (or which Greek text for that matter) was used as well.

Comment: I have a number of translations that have indeed helped my language-learning :) As for Louis Segond, my version's introduction lists the particular Masoretic and Greek texts used for the Old and New Testaments respectively, so I think the Hebrew was indeed the basis. That said, it is true that translations of Hebrew scriptures do often include footnotes to the effect that difficult or uncertain passages have been clarified using the LXX.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+Revised+Standard+Version&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20Revised%20Standard%20Version%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3):

In your sentence, *lequel* is used because if *qui* was used, it would reference *l'Égypte*:

> Un nouveau roi vint à régner sur l'Égypte, **qui** sortait d'une guerre contre [...]

There are other ways to formulate this as you mentioned, but this phrasing is kind of elevated and ceremonial, so it fits well in writings like the Bible.

It's not very common in spoken French, but it can be found in written texts, especially when they're elevated.

Answer (score 2):

*Lequel* is still used as a subject today in non interrogative phrases, but essentially in written French.

Just google *lequel a déclaré* or *lequel a refusé* to find common examples.

Comment: Does this work for objects too? *La question trois sur le test, laquelle le prof voulait poser à la classe.*

Comment: @LukeSawczak We would use *que* or *celle que* here: *La troisième question du test, celle que le professeur voulait poser à la classe.* P.S. It took me almost four years to answer to your comments, but I didn't work on it full time ;-)