# Confusion dans l'usage de « laquelle »

Tags: grammaire

Je m'interroge sur l'usage de « laquelle ». Pourquoi n'utilise-t-on pas « dont », ou bien « de laquelle » ? Voici un exemple :

> La limitation est seulement une négation d'une plus grande perfection,
>   laquelle négation n'est point par une cause, mais bien la chose
>   limitée.

Comment: See here https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30938/lequel-as-relative-subject-pronoun-instead-of-qui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pourquoi employer une forme plutôt que l'autre est une question de choix personnel et aussi une question de distance entre le mot remplacé et le pronom ; l'avantage des pronoms de forme « -quel(le)(s) » est qu'ils ont un genre que l'on doit accorder avec le nom remplacé et que de plus on peut ajouter le mot remplacé à côté, ce qui fait que lorsque le mot remplacé est loin du pronom on l'identifie plus facilement.

- La limitation est seulement une négation d'une plus grande perfection, **qui** n'est point par une cause, mais bien la chose limitée.

*On ne sait pas trop bien dans la phrase ci-dessus, laquelle est grammaticalement correcte, quel est l'antécédent ; est-ce « perfection » ? Est-ce « limitation » ?*
 Dans la phrase telle que vous la citez on identifie immédiatement l'antécédant parce que l'on peut le répéter avec « laquelle », alors que ce n'est pas possible avec « qui ».
En d'autres mots ces pronoms permettent de choisir aisément un antécédent dans la proposition qui précède.

« Laquelle » est ici un pronom sujet ;

- L'homme lui a donné une montre, **laquelle** a appartenu à son grand-père. *La montre, (représentée par « laquelle ») a appartenu à son grand-père.*

« Laquelle » peut aussi être un pronom objet direct;

- Il a apporté une machine, **laquelle** j'ai refusée, parce qu'elle est en panne. *« Laquelle » remplace « machine » ; donc, cela revient à « j'ai refusé la machine »  (« laquelle » représente « machine » ; « laquelle » ne peut pas être sujet parce qu'il y a déjà un sujet pour le verbe « refuser » (c'est « je », sous forme élidée : « j' »)).*

Lorsque l'on veut un pronom selon la forme de « quel » et « quelle », c'est à dire un pronom qui inclut le genre dans sa morphologie et qu'en plus on veut qu'il ait pour fonction dans la phrase celle de « complément d'objet indirect », il faut compléter l'utilisation du pronom (dans le présent cas, « laquelle »), par une préposition, comme suit :  « à laquelle », « de laquelle » pour un COI.

**COI**

- L'élève **à laquelle** il a permis de partir tôt avait d'excellentes notes.
- La plage **de laquelle** il ne veut plus entendre parler sera vendue à un cheikh d'Arabie Saoudite.

Si dans certaines des phrases d'exemple qui ont été utilisées ci-dessus on est forcé de se servir d'un pronom de type « -quel(le) » il y a toujours les cas simple pour lesquels les deux possibilités sont équivalentes.

- Les poupées, lesquelles elle n'aimait plus, furent mises au grenier.
- Les poupées, qu'elle n'aimait plus, furent mises au grenier.

Il faut cependant se souvenir que *ces pronoms ne s'utilisent pas dans le mode déterminatif, mais toujours dans le mode descriptif* lorsque leur fonction est soit **sujet** soit **objet**;

- La maison qu'elle avait achetée vient de bruler.
- <s>La maison laquelle elle avait achetée vient de brûler.</s>

Cela signifie qu'une virgule est nécessaire pour séparer la proposition précédente du pronom et une virgule est nécessaire pour terminer la proposition introduite par le pronom.

**COI**

- L'élève **à laquelle** il a permis de partir tôt avait d'excellentes notes. (*L'élève est du sexe féminin.*)
- L'élève, **à laquelle** il a permis de partir tôt, avait d'excellentes notes.
- L'élève **à qui** il a permis de partir tôt avait d'excellentes notes. (*Dans le cas présent, on ne sait pas si l'élève est un garçon ou une fille.*)
- L'élève, **à qui** il a permis de partir tôt, avait d'excellentes notes.
- La plage **de laquelle** il ne veut plus entendre parler sera vendue à un cheikh d'Arabie Saoudite.
- La plage, **de laquelle** il ne veut plus entendre parler, sera vendue à un cheikh d'Arabie Saoudite.
- La plage **dont** il ne veut plus entendre parler sera vendue à un cheikh d'Arabie Saoudite.
- La plage, **dont** il ne veut plus entendre parler, sera vendue à un cheikh d'Arabie Saoudite.