# Please explain difference in usage between qui and lequel

Tags: grammaire, usage

As far as I understand *lequel* is used only with prepositions so if there's no preposition, I need to use *qui*, is it right?

In some videos on YouTube, people explain that *qui* is used only with people and *lequel* with inanimate objects. On other websites there is an explanation that *qui* can be used with things too.

I am totally confused  :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you speak Russian? (I see your name). I could try to explain it in Russian.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language Stack Exchange.  I see another related question here: ["Lequel" as relative subject pronoun (instead of qui)](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30938/lequel-as-relative-subject-pronoun-instead-of-qui?rq=1)  The tag [pronom relatif] has a lot of help, too.  Please stick around to take the [tour] and see the [help].

Comment: @oreste да, если не трудно, объясните на русском :)

Comment: Je pense que si quelqu'un a écrit "i" et non "I", c'est son style, et il ne faut pas y toucher, ce n'est pas une faute.

Comment: Je vais écrire en russe, j'espère que c'est correct, de toute façon, la question est verouillée. // Здесь хорошее объяснение [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3508), с примерами. Вкратце если одушевленное лицо, можно оба, _lequel_ более высокий уровень, если неодушевленное _lequel_. После предлога обычно  _lequel_.

Answer (score 3):

Il existe 2 types de pronoms relatifs :

- les formes simples (qui, que, quoi, dont, où) : qui s’utilise pour la fonction sujet et peut représenter un antécédent animé ou inanimé ; que a pour fonction COD ou attribut et représente un antécédent animé ou inanimé ; quoi est utilisé avec des prépositions pour l’inanimé ; qui est utilisé avec des prépositions pour l’animé ; dont est utilisé pour l’animé et l’inanimé lorsque la proposition est « de » ; où est utilisé avec un antécédent de lieu ou de temps.
- les formes composées (lequel et déclinaisons, auquel/duquel et leurs déclinaisons) : on les utilise avec des prépositions et ils ont un antécédent animé ou inanimé.

Exemples :
L’homme qui parle, la voiture qui roule (sujet)

L’homme que je vois, le problème que je rencontre (COD)

L’homme dont il parle, l’exploit dont il est fier (préposition de)

L’homme avec qui/lequel je parle, l’arme avec laquelle il se bat

Le moment où il est arrivé, l’endroit où il est arrivé

L’amie avec laquelle il parle, l’objet auquel il fait référence

Comment: Je trouve l'explication claire et plutôt compréhensive, maid J'ai un doute.  Vous dîtes: «quoi est utilisé avec des prépositions pour l’inanimé», mais vous ne fournissez aucun exemple de cet usage.  Est-ce qu c'est une omission intentionnelle?  Est-qu'on peut dire sans hésitation «l'arme avec quoi il se bat» et «l'object à quoi il fait référence»?

Comment: « Quoi » est un pronom relatif un peu particulier car il ne peut pas avoir pour antécédent un nom mais un pronom ou une proposition. Il représente dans tous les cas quelque chose d’inanimé (une chose, une notion, une phrase précédente). 


Exemples : c’est quelque chose à quoi je n’avais pas pensé. C’est ce sur quoi il se mettent d’accord. Il l’a appelé, après quoi il est parti. 


« L’arme avec quoi » est incorrect car l’antécédent « arme » est un nom—> l’arme avec laquelle

Comment: Je dirais ensuite que la différence dépend de la référence.  Si on fait référence a un 'inanimé de signification générale ou générique, il faut utiliser "quoi."  Si on fait  référence a un inanimé qui désigne un objet ou un concept spécifique, il faut utiliser les formes composées.

Comment: Vous avez un exemple ?

Comment: Vous avez déjà proposé la première partie d'un example:  « c’est quelque chose à quoi je n’avais pas pensé.» versus «c'est une chose à laquelle je n’avais pas pensé.»

Comment: Tout à fait. Dans la première phrase, on utilise « à quoi » car « quelque chose » n’est pas un nom mais un pronom indéfini. Dans la deuxième phrase on utilise « à laquelle » car « chose » est un nom.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Anastasia to the French StackExchange!

As I understand it, your question is about the usage of the relative pronouns with prepositions.  In other cases, the usage of the relative pronouns is mostly the same with people and things, except in cases where there is no specific antecedent.  In this latter case you use "ce que/qui" to refer to generic things, but have several choices when referring to generic people.  Using "celui/celle/ceux/celles que/qui" is structurally the same as using "ce que/qui"; however, you can also just supply a general noun as an antecedent (e.g., les personne que/qui) or use "qui" alone in higher registers in some phrases (e.g. "Qui vivra, verra").

When it comes to using relative pronouns with prepositions, the usage often differs according to whether the pronoun refers to a person or an object.  There are special rules when the pronoun would ordinarily be "de" that sometimes require or permit you to use "dont" instead of "de" with a relative pronoun.  With general expressions of place or time, it is frequent and maybe normal to replace the relative pronoun and preposition with "où" (i.e., "j'ai visité la région où ils travaillent" or "au moment où il est parti").

Historically, you might expect "que" to be used with prepositions, but this puts it in a stressed position and so "quoi" is phonetically the only option.  "Quoi," however, is only used to refer to things that have no inherent gender, such as whole phrases, unnamed concepts, or generic pronouns (e.g., "ce," "cela," or "quelque chose").

For anything with a specific noun antecedent, you can use the appropriate form of "lequel"; however, this form can feel a little "heavy" when used to apply to people.  With people, it is common to borrow from the interrogative pronouns and use "qui" with prepositions, except in more formal registers when using "lequel" and its specific gender and number forms can make its reference clearer (e.g., "les personnes avec qui/lesquelles je travaille").  With nouns referring to things, you just use "lequel," since there is no other handy option to choose (e.g., "la table sur laquelle je travaille").

When relative pronouns are used to replace nouns used with "de," I think it is mandatory to replace the pronoun and preposition with "dont" when the meaning indicates "possession" or "attribution" ("la femme dont je connais le fils."  With combined prepositions, like "à côté de," or "à cause de" you have to use "duquel, de laquelle, etc."  In other cases, I think either "dont" or "duquel" or "qui" (with people) can be used, but perhaps without the same frequency or register ("La femme de qui/de laquelle/dont je parle" or "l'histoire de laquelle/dont je parle").